# Calculate working hours of specific month of each employee

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, query-builder

I'm using symfony3, I have an entity called Presence to register entry time and out time of each employee.
The registration works good but I'd like to calculate the total of working hours of specific month.

In fact , I use this method to calculate the total of working hours by day:

```
 public function hoursByDay()
 {
    $interval1 = $this->entryTimeFirstHalf->diff($this->entryTimeFirstHalfr);
    $interval2 = $this->entryTimeSecondHalf->diff($this->outTimeSecondHalf);

    $e = new \DateTime('00:00');
    $f = clone $e;

    $e->add($interval1);
    $e->add($interval2);

    return $f->diff($e)->format("%H:%I");
}
```

But I didn't reach to calculate the total of working hours **by month.**

```
/**
* Presence
*
* @ORM\Table(name="presence")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PresenceRepository")
*/
class Presence
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_presence", type="date")
 */
private $date;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="entry_time_first_half", type="time")
 */
private $entryTimeFirstHalf;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="out_time_first_half", type="time")
 */
private $outTimeFirstHalf;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="entry_time_second_half", type="time")
 */
private $entryTimeSecondHalf;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="out_time_second_half", type="time")
 */
private $outTimeSecondHalf;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Employee")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $employee;
```

Comment: Would you like do by SQL? or by ORM? you can get your result by SQL easily.

Comment: Do you have an example how to do it by SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL:

```
SELECT `employee_id`, SUM( TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, `entry_time_first_half`, `out_time_second_half` )) 
FROM `presence`
WHERE MONTH(`date`) = 7 AND YEAR(`date`) = 2018
GROUP BY `employee`
```